# Fileupload control in ASP.Net 4 how to return failure reason?

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-4.0

I have a simple web page on my intranet that I can use to upload a file toa "drop" folder. Some of my users aren't able to upload the files. How do I get details on what caused the upload failure?

I know it has something to do with rights but I need to get a little more detail.

Any suggestions?

TIA 
J

Comment: It could be permissions, it could be the size of the files, it could be a lot of things, hardly to say without the code, but You can save a log when you get an Exception in the upload process

Comment: The event log suggestion Ben made is the easiest, you can also wrap your code in a Try/Catch and log the error error yourself.  You should consider implementing some type of global logging and error management solution (e.g. ELMAH, log4net, etc...).  Most can now be downloaded and integrated using NUGET.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the application event log on the web server and there will be details of any uncaught exceptions thrown by asp.net